# Why is int16 type limit 32,768 if 16 bits max is 65,535?

Tags: c#, clr

Sum of 16 bits all "1" bits will result 65,535:

first byte:
1(128) 1(64) 1(32) 1(16)        1(8) 1(4) 1(2) 1(1)

second byte:
1(327,68) 1(16,384) 1(8,192) 1(4,096)    1(2,048) 1(1,024) 1(512) 1(256)

which the decimal would be:

32,768 + 16,384 + 8,192 + 4,096 + 2,048 + 1,024 + 512 + 256 + 128 + 64 + 32 + 16 + 8 + 4 + 2 + 1

total is: 65,535

the max of int16 should be 65,535 and 32,768(which is just 1000 0000 0000 0000)

I can't see how it would be otherwise.

Comment: Max value != type limit.  These are signed types, so they go from (e.g., Int16) -32768 to 32767

Comment: Comes all down to unsigned and signed integers.

Comment: *Unsigned* UInt16.MaxValue is 65535

Comment: of course, feeling stupid

Comment: It is a basic question to ask, however I do think this is a valid question, I don't understand why all the down vote?

Comment: @IgorMeszaros: I didn't downvote - but maybe the reason is this could very easily have been checked by searching online first.

Comment: That depends on ones googling skills. for me the first find is this, then some useless msdn link, and the rest isn't any better. On might miss the fact that this has to do with signed and unsigned int.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes either, hovering over the down vote button it states `This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful`. Clearly this is not the case. As effort is shown,  its clear and directly answerable.

Comment: Having typed "why is int16 limit 32,768" into google (after this question which would not have been in the results) the top result is "Why is the range of ints -32768 to 32767" - on SO, The second is "Integer, Int16, Int32, Int64" & the available text shows the limits for a "signed" integer. The 3rd result is "Integer Limits" from MSDN. So I think it does meet the first criteria "This question does not show any research effort;"

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Because it ranges from -32,768 to 32,767, which in sum is 65,536 (0 is included here) possible values.

If you use `UInt16` (which stands for unsigned int16) you can give it a value of 65,535.

Comment: So one bit is used for declaring if its positive/negative?

Comment: @MuhammedGül - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement - "Two's complement is the most common method of representing signed integers on computers"

Comment: @OliverEvans Yes that’s another method. “The four best-known methods of extending the binary numeral system to represent signed numbers are: sign-and-magnitude, ones' complement, two's complement, and offset binary."

Answer (score 5):

There is a difference between a signed and an unsigned integer.
One has the ability to be negative and the other one doesn't.

It also is not just for int16, but for other types as well.

```
+--------+----------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------+
|  Type  |            Min             |            Max             |           Size           |
+--------+----------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------+
| sbyte  | -128                       | 127                        | Signed 8-bit integer     |
| byte   | 0                          | 255                        | Unsigned 8-bit integer   |
| char   | U+0000                     | U+ffff                     | Unicode 16-bit character |
| short  | -32,768                    | 32,767                     | Signed 16-bit integer    |
| ushort | 0                          | 65,535                     | Unsigned 16-bit integer  |
| int    | -2,147,483,648             | 2,147,483,647              | Signed 32-bit integer    |
| uint   | 0                          | 4,294,967,295              | Unsigned 32-bit integer  |
| long   | -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 | 9,223,372,036,854,775,807  | Signed 64-bit integer    |
| ulong  | 0                          | 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 | Unsigned 64-bit integer  |
+--------+----------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------+
```

Answer (score 3):

Int16 is signed. The most significant bit denotes sign (0 for positive, 1 for negative). The highest number achievable with 0 as MSB is 0111 1111 1111 1111, which is 32767 in decimal.

It is designed this way, so that unsigned addition/subtraction would work on signed numbers as well. So, to get -1, you subtract 1 from 0, and get 1111 1111 1111 1111 (due to overflow). If you keep subtracting, you eventually reach 1000 0000 0000 0000 = -32768 (dec), which is the lowest negative number representable as int16.

So, 2^16 = 65536, which is the total number of representable values. This adds up from: (a) 1 value for zero, (b) 32767 positive numbers, (c) 32768 negative numbers.

Answer (score 2):

That's difference between signed int and unsigned int. 16-bit unsigned int ranges in [0, 65535]. While 16-bit signed int ranges [-32768, 32767]. The max of int16 should be 32767 instead of 32768.

Answer (score 1):

You're forgetting the sign. int16 is a signed type, so it's actually:

first byte: ...
second byte: sign(+ or -) 1(16,384) ...

Which covers the range from -32768 to 32767 (0 is considered a positive).
Most of the time, 0 is used for positive and 1 for negative: [Sign bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_bit)

It would be an entirely different matter if it was a uint16 (u for unsigned):

first byte: ...
second byte: 1(32768) ...

Which, in turn, ranges from 0 to 65535.